# Definitions for the ClassID in USPS Rate Calculator API

Tags: api, rate, usps

I am wondering if anyone knows where I might be able to find the definitions for each of the ClassIDs that USPS returns in the Rate Calculator API response?

I have been looking all over for this, but can't find any actual documentation on it anywhere. I don't know how USPS expects use to simply know what these values mean.

Note that all the [API Documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/rate-calculator-api.htm) says about the ClassID is:

> A mail class identifier for the postage returned. Not necessarily unique within a <Package/>.

Answer (score 2):

This file has the list of them, in Appendix A:

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/2013-july-webtools-release-notes.rtf

Not sure where its linked on the USPS site, but I'll update if I come across it.

Answer (score 1):

The following documentation is the best I've found which I've confirmed with a USPS technical integration HQ rep:

[image]

The list continues...

Source: https://docs.rocketship.it/php/1-0/usps-class-ids.html